# How to make sure all properties of the object are set not using constructor?

Tags: java, oop, constructor, initialization

I have a class with more than 10 properties.

I want to make sure all properties are provided **while creating** an object from this class.

Is there a better solution than using a constructor providing all the properties values or instances?

Comment: Properties of an object can't be set before an instance is created.

Comment: *"I want to make sure all properties are set before creating an object from this class"* ... that's impossible.

Comment: Your question is unclear: You cannot set properties of an object before creating an instance of a class, except you want to make them `static`.

Comment: Can you explain "are provided" ? it could mean "not null", "not null and filled by some injected service" etc. Providing a default value (not null) can be an option, but there is no checking.

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot I mean all properties must get a value and could not be null

Comment: @SamaneZadabbas What about providing default value ? eg., `public List<DateTime> OpenList {get;set;} = new List<DateTime>();` Outside this, constructor dependency injection has among other things this purpose too. `public MyClass(IService service){_service = service} public AnotherInjectedProperty => _service.AnotherProperty;`.

Comment: Another option is to provide a property with logic: `public SomeType MyProperty => _myProperty ?? (_myProperty = new MyProperty());`. Another option is to provide a base class that will provide property values `public SuperClass:BaseClass(){}` and `public BaseClass(){MyProperty = new PropertyClass()}.

Comment: I understand "while creating" as "before the end of the scope of the constructor". Is it correct?

Comment: So, the advantage of default value, it that it will be executed before any constructor, and will be commmon to all constructors. The advantage of property will logic is that it will ensure a non null value, but it can take another value from a service or some constructor. The advantage of base class, is its reusability if several super class are using it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) comes to mind. Create a builder for your class that lets you set all the properties and add a validation to the final build-step that returns null or throws an exception if any properties are missing.

This might be a lot of work just to avoid having a constructor with a really long parameter list, but it might be worth it. In the end, it depends on your use-case.